Receiving HTML response from API instead of JSON
I am trying to consume an API inside of a useEffect hook and it's leading to CORS issue.
To resolve this I am trying to set up proxy middleaware. After this I am not getting the CORS issue but instead of the JSON response from the API, I am receiving a HTML body. I am not really sure what and how to resolve this as I am learning React and not really sure where to look into this.
proxy middleware
created a addProxyMiddleware.js file inside '../server/addProxyMiddleware' and added this code -
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');
module.exports = function addProxyMiddleware(app){
    app.use('/dapi', createProxyMiddleware({
        target: 'https://www.apiUrl.com',
        changeOrigin: true
    }));
}

inside of bodyComp.js component (where I am consuming the API), added this code -
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
const BodyComp = () => {

    const [restaurantList, setrestaurantList] = useState(resDataList);
    useEffect(()=>{
        fetchData();
    },[]);

    const fetchData = async () => {
        console.log('fetchData');
        const data = await fetch(
            "/dapi/restaurants/list/v5?lat=28.6105073&lng=77.1145653&is-seo-homepage-enabled=true&page_type=DESKTOP_WEB_LISTING"
        );

        const jsonData = await data.json();
        console.log(jsonData);
    };
    return(  
        <div className="bodyCls">
        </div>
    );
}
export default BodyComp;

After this I am receiving below response in the console -
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON


Do you have a CORS issue or do you have an issue processing a response that isn't JSON? Please [edit] to clarify what the exact specific issue is.

@DrewReese, it is exactly i have mentioned. I was having a CORS issue but then after adding the middleware i am receiving a response that is not JSON. I am not really sure which one is causing what issue, as i just started learning react and faced this issue. I thought of including both in the question.

Check the response in the network inspector. I bet  there is some 4xx error and the backend delivers a default error page ... Therefore it's good practice to check response.ok or response.status before trying to access the response body ...

How is that GET request resolving? What is the response value? It seems whatever it is that it isn't JSON. But the error already tells you this and there's nothing else for us to use to help you. We need some debugging details.

Also make sure the request to your desired api actually works with a tool like PostMan or similar. Because if that api already returnd a 4xx and a error document, there is not much you can do about that in your backend

@derpirscher, I just check with postman. It is weird, because i am receiving a HTML body along with 403 forbidden code from the response. But, on the browser url , if i am entering the api, i can see a json response.

open devtools - network. then find your request. what is documentType? and what in tab Response?

@amarsik1,
request headers -
GET /dapi/restaurants/list/v5?lat=28.6105073&lng=77.1145653&is-seo-homepage-enabled=true&page_type=DESKTOP_WEB_LISTING HTTP/1.1 Accept: */* Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br, zstd Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9 Connection: keep-alive Host: localhost:1234 If-Modified-Since: Tue, 09 Apr 2024 19:11:04 GMT Referer: http://localhost:1234/ Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin

I'm curious, is the "DESKTOP_WEB_LISTING" part of the request URL supposed to be some value you are injecting, or is that literally the page_type parameter value?

@JK1990 receiving a 403 may have to do something with authentication. When you do that from your browser it might be ok because dome cookie is sent with the request. But when sent from postman or with your proxy middleware that authentication info may be missing or ve wrong...

It just seems like the endpoint is returning HTML, not JSON, can you have a look at the content type header and confirm? The CORS issues is likely solved by your solution, not so sure what changeOrigin does but make sure it satisfies your security needs.
But back to the JSON/HTML issue, the fact the endpoint ends with page_type=DESKTOP_WEB_LISTING suggests it's returning HTML, a page to act as a listing, it sounds like HTML.
